# Unzip not replacing file

Tags: c#, zip

I have a problem with a zip file replacing an existing file. I have looked at other examples on here and I still can't seem to figure it out...
I have a `loop` that writes some stats of the file extracted into a textbox. I think that its this line:

`if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileUnzipFullName))`

**My Code:**

```
    public void UnzipFileNew()
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n" + "EXTRACTING!");

        String rootpath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        //This stores the path where the file should be unzipped to,
        //including any subfolders that the file was originally in.
        string fileUnzipFullPath;

        //This is the full name of the destination file including
        //the path
        string fileUnzipFullName;

        //Opens the zip file up to be read
        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(@"update.zip"))
        {
            //Loops through each file in the zip file
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
            {

                //Outputs file information to the Textbox
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("File Name: "+ file.Name);
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("File Size: bytes "+ file.Length);
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n");
                richTextBox1.AppendText("Compression Ratio: "+ ((double)file.CompressedLength / file.Length).ToString("0.0%"));
                richTextBox1.AppendText("\r\n");

                //Identifies the destination file name and path
                fileUnzipFullName = Path.Combine(rootpath, file.FullName); //fileUnzipFullName = Path.Combine(@"Example\", file.FullName);

                //Extracts 
                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileUnzipFullName))
                {

                    fileUnzipFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileUnzipFullName);

                    //Creates the directory if it doesn't exist
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(fileUnzipFullPath);

                    //Extracts the file to (potentially new) path
                    file.ExtractToFile(fileUnzipFullName);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileUnzipFullName))` will indeed prevent you even trying to extract the file if it already exists. So you will need to remove this or change it as per your use case.

Additionally, the `ExtractToFile` method will throw an `IOException` if the file already exists as you are using it. Fortunately, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485718(v=vs.110).aspx) reveals that there is an overload with a boolean flag for overwriting:

```
public static void ExtractToFile(
    this ZipArchiveEntry source,
    string destinationFileName,
    bool overwrite
)
```

So instead of

```
file.ExtractToFile(fileUnzipFullName);
```

use

```
file.ExtractToFile(fileUnzipFullName, true);
```

---

Using your code, this will indiscriminately overwrite all files with the ones extracted from the zip:

```
//Extracts 
//if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileUnzipFullName))
//{
    fileUnzipFullPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileUnzipFullName);

    //Creates the directory if it doesn't exist
    Directory.CreateDirectory(fileUnzipFullPath);

    //Extracts the file to (potentially new) path
    file.ExtractToFile(fileUnzipFullName, true);
//}
```

Comment: Thank you John! This did work! I added a folder to the zip with a file to replace another file in a folder in the root directory. I got an error:  `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\stump\source\repos\UpdaterTest\UpdaterTest\bin\Debug\resources\test\'.' ` it gets thrown in that same  `file.ExtractToFile(fileUnzipFullName, true);`

Comment: Oh, I think you need the actual _filename_. IIRC `GetDirectoryName` provides only the directory. If you comment out that line, I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply! but I seemed to get errors when I comment out that line. I have also tried the other lines associated with `GetDirectoryName`